# Missing Calendar inbox on desktop

Tags: mac, imac, calendar, dock, notifications

I receive notification (in both the notification center dock) of changes to our (family) shared calendar, though unlike my iPhone and Macbook Pro, the inbox is nowhere to be found on my iMac (Late 2013). The notification icon remains in my dock and I can't clear it. Any idea where or how I can get my inbox button back?

OSX El Capitan (v 10.11.6), Calendar v 8.0

What I see;

[notification in dock. Had to pull the image as my reputation doesn't allow more than 2 links. Urg]

[image: No inbox button available]

[missing inbox in calendar application]

What I'd like to see (as available on my Macbook (2009. El Capitan) and iphone (4S) but missing on my desktop);

[image: calendar with inbox button]

[screencap lifted from another post with inbox button. Also available on my macbook, running same OS]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Has been driving me nuts for quite a while now.

Cheers!

Comment: Is the calendar definitely enabled, in the list on the left? Also, what happens if you post a family calendar event from that machine?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin. Calendar is definitely enabled (a whole slew of them, actually). And nothing unexpected happens when I post a family calendar event from my macbook (or my imac. or phone). I receive the download notification button on my macbook and phone, but not this iMac. (Though I do receive the fly-in notification on the top-right of my screen - outside of the Calendar app, as I do other notifications (apps, reminders, etc). Might this create conflict? Not confirmed, but I likely receive the same fly-in notification on my macbook, as I do others)

Comment: **RESOLVED** On my iMac, my notifications settings were "Settings > Notifications > Calendar > Calendar alert style > Alerts" which remained until I clicked on the alert (launching Calendar on the related date) or dismissed clicking "ok". Doing so removed the notification from the Calendar app, along with the inbox button. I took note with the Calendar application and notifications open (they typically greeted me on startup). Cheers!

Comment: Glad you got it. I'd set that as the answer then - you can answer your own posts & mark them correct - so future Googlers can find it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Tetsujin. I did just that. Cheers! (now... If I could only figure out how to get AskDifferent reply notifications by email... ;)

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/ optionally with your user number added at the end, though it should work without, if you're logged in

Comment: haha, thanks very much! (the email was bundled in my gmail "forum" category. Seems I have to keep a better eye on that... Cheers!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED** On my iMac, my notifications settings were "Settings > Notifications > Calendar > Calendar alert style > Alerts" which remained until I clicked on the alert (launching Calendar on the related date) or dismissed clicking "ok". Doing so removed the notification from the Calendar app, along with the inbox button. I took note with the Calendar application and notifications open (they typically greeted me on startup). Cheers!